# Automate data loading from folder to SAS lib

Tags: sas

I want to automate the process of loading data from folder to SAS LASR Server (but I expect it must be similar to just loading data in normal SAS Lib). I have a folder where user can put their data (lets say *.csv files with the same structure). I want to create some sort of process which will automatically scan this folder, check if there are any new files and if any - append it to existing data and upload it to make available to all users for further analysis.

I know how to read separate CSV to SAS dataset and I'm looking for the easiest way to do solve two problems - comparing current CSVs with already uploaded and making this process scheduled.

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This is doable with base SAS, but I would suggest you look into VA autoload features, e.g. http://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2016/04/04/sas-visual-analytics-autoload-configuration-made-easy/

Comment: Thank you, Quentin, that's great but the problem is that I want to run some sort of checks and data manipulations before loading data to VA... But anyway this post is very useful and I'll definitely will use this capabilities later!